# Image hiding/slicing from top and bottom in responsive website

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive website and now when it is almost complete now i realize that the image height is 30px too much.
As I have few thousand product images, it will be very labours to edit all the images.

So I am looking for some solution that the image is 15px from the top and 15px from bottom sliced is

What will be the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have each image in some container you can do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="yourimage.jpg"  width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container img {
  position:relative;
  top:-15px;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/ysH4Q/6/